# NameError: global name 'NoneType' is not defined in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, bigdata

I have written a UDF to replace a few specific date values in a column named "latest_travel_date" with 'NA'. However, this column also contains many null values, so I have handled this also in the UDF. (please see below)

```
Query:
def date_cleaner(date_col):
    if type(date_col) == NoneType:
        pass
    else:
        if year(date_col) in ('1899','1900'):
            date_col= 'NA'
        else:
            pass
    return date_col

date_cleaner_udf = udf(date_cleaner, DateType())

Df3= Df2.withColumn("latest_cleaned", date_cleaner_udf("latest_travel_date"))
```

**However, I am continuously getting the error:
NameError: global name 'NoneType' is not defined**

Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

This issue could be solved by two ways.

If you try to find the Null values from your dataFrame you should use the [NullType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.NullType).

Like this:

```
if type(date_col) == NullType
```

Or you can find if the date_col is None like this:

```
if date_col is None
```

I hope this help.

Comment: I tried with both the options as you suggested, but it ends up in the error:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

Comment: Can you do something? Can you add to your question a part of your dataframe. I did the same thing as you did in my spark. But this issue didn't happens. We need to see this dataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
if type(date_col) == NoneType:
```

It looks like you actually want:

```
if date_col is None:
```

Comment: When I do this, it results in the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

Comment: @Preyas is that reported from the same line? What's your stack trace?

Comment: No the line generating the error changes between the two queries.

Comment: @Preyas, it sounds like you must have code elsewhere that is operating on an object that is None. You should find the source of that stack trace and ensure that the operation is bypassed in the case where the input is None.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Michael, you cannot do

```
if type(date_col) == NoneType:
```

However, changing that to `None` won't complete the task. There is another issue with

```
date_col= 'NA'
```

It is of `StringType` but you declared the return type to be `DateType`. Your `_jvm` error in the comment was complaining this mis-match of data types.

It seems you just want to mark `date_col` to be `None` when it is `1899` or `1900`, and drop all Nulls. If so, you can do this:

```
def date_cleaner(date_col):
    if date_col:
        if year(date_col) in ('1899','1900'):
            return None

    return date_col

date_cleaner_udf = udf(date_cleaner, DateType())

Df3= Df2.withColumn("latest_cleaned", date_cleaner_udf("latest_travel_date")).dropna(subset=["latest_travel_date"])
```

This is because `DateType` could either take a valid datetime or Null (by default). You could do [`dropna`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna) to "clean" your dataframe.